# No puedo resolver el error R android

Tags: java, android

Estoy desesperado. A ver si alguien no se da por vencido y puede ayudarme a solucionarlo

Creo que ya he visto más de 10 páginas sobre como solucionar el error R en android. pero ninguna de las soluciones me vale.

Mi proyecto funcionaba bien y de repente todas las referencias a R fallan. en todos los archivos. Me pasó una vez y por actualizar android me apareció, copie todo el código del proyecto y creé un proyecto nuevo, pegué el código y parece que en ese nuevo si que funcionaba bien. Esta vez ha aparecido por las buenas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya he hecho el Clean Project, Rebuild Project, reiniciado Android Studio y nada, sigue apareciendo. Estoy desesperado e impotente con este error. Para los que estamos empezando es una desesperación.

¿ Cómo lo soluciono ?

Fotos de los errores: ( aparecen en absolutamente todos los archivos con referencias a R

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: localiza el R y clica sobre el y si aparece una linea blanca debajo presiona alt + enter y pone import class.

Comment: No da esa opción

Comment: podrias publicar una foto de como te aparece el error ?

Comment: publica el código, usualmente si falla la carga o el buil se debe a algún error critico o a la falta de algún componente o elemento de la app como un recurso, incluso una libnea de texto faltante pero que estes declarando te genera este error, revisa el log de errores para determinar donde esta el elemento faltante y luego realiza un clear project

Comment: El proyecto funcionaba, le di al play, cerré y ya no volvió a funcionar. Quieres que pegue todos los archivos ? :S

Comment: Ahí tienes unas fotos @GastónSaillén

Comment: te fijaste si en el androidManifest el paquete es el mismo que se importa con R en las clases?

Comment: No se cual se importa con R en las clases, donde lo miro ? en el Manifest el package="com.android.rodry.allchistes" y es el mismo que tienen los activity

Comment: porfavor estoy desesperado, no consigo como solucionarlo, si croe un proyecto nuevo y pego codigos, me ocurre lo mismo, una vez me funciono, pero me ocurre lo mismo aunque cambie la direccion del paquete.. ASí es imposible aprender

Comment: @Rodrypaladin veo que continuas con este problema, recuerda que si buscas referencias a elementos mediante findViewbyId() estas referencias deben existir el en .xml cargado a la activity mediante setContentView() . Tienes tu proyecto en algún repositorio para revisarlo?

Comment: Claro que esos elementos existen en el xml cargado en el activity, y ahi está en setContentView(R.layout.nombre_activity) pero la R siempre roja

Comment: @Jorgesys es que aunque lo empiece de cero si pego el xml de otro proyecto,  cambiando el nombre del paquete, me saltan los errores R luego en todo el codigo del proyecto

Comment: pueden ser muchas causas como error en algún xml (incluso espacios, alguna comilla que falte ...), con algún vector drawable, aparte de importar el R en java, aveces actualizando Android(sdk)

Comment: Te propongo que agregues a tu pregunta un caso concreto donde tengas el problema: una Activity por ejemplo, que agregues el código Java y los layout que usa esa activity, todos los layout que use, sea el contenedor, sean los menus, etc. Por ejemplo ¿cuando abres los layouts no te marca ningún error en ellos?

Comment: Hola, tu problema no es el R, por eso no podes solucionarlo, el R se genera cuando se logra compilar correctamente el proyecto, seguramente tienes un error en el build.gradle y por eso tu proyecto no compila entonces no puede generar el R y en el codigo aparece como un error, por eso aveces pasa cuando actualizas cosas. Copia el codigo de ambos build.gradle y veamos si hay un error ahí.

Comment: Si antes funcionaba correctamente puedes restaurar la versión anterior de tu proyecto de esta forma: Cambia de vista a Android en la parte izquierda del Android Studio, haz clic con el botón derecho en el nodo de la app , Local History , Show History . A continuación, busque la revisión que desea volver, haga clic derecho en él y elija Revert . Todo su proyecto se revertirá a este estado.